# How can i generalize method invocation among servlets?

Tags: java, servlets, reflection

I have the following code inside `doPost()` in one of my controllers. This code basically takes the `action` parameter from the request and executes a method having the same name as the value of action.

```
// get the action from the request and then execute the necessary
    // action.
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    try {
        Method method = UserController.class.getDeclaredMethod(action,
                new Class[] { HttpServletRequest.class,
                        HttpServletResponse.class });
        try {
            method.invoke(this, request, response);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

        ErrorHandlingHelper.redirectToErrorPage(response);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now I want to implement this functionality in all my controllers. I tried to generalize it putting it inside a function in a `helper` class but I am unable to get the right way.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

UserController.class.getDeclaredMethod(string, args) returns the method if it is declared in the class UserController.

You can make all your servlet classes inherit by a parent servlet, as Funtik suggested and then add this method in the superclass:

```
protected Method methodToInvoke(String action) {
    Class[] args =  { HttpServletRequest.class,
                    HttpServletResponse.class };
    Method method = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(action, args);
}
```

This method searches to find a method of the class of servlet that is being executed (this.getClass()). You can also include the execution method in the supertype sevlet class.

Alternatively, if you don't want or just can't subclass all your servlets, you can put this functionality in a utility class, but then you should pass the servlet class as a parameter.

```
protected static Method methodToInvoke(String action, Class clazz) {
    Class[] args =  { HttpServletRequest.class,
                    HttpServletResponse.class };
    Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(action, args);
}
```

But then you should pass this.getClass() as an argument when you call this static method from a servlet.

You can also take a look at http://code.google.com/p/bo2/source/browse/trunk/Bo2Utils/main/gr/interamerican/bo2/utils/ReflectionUtils.java. It contains some of the utilities that you need (find a method, execute it etc)

Answer (score -1):

have you tried inheritance?

Make an abstract `ParentServlet` and override `doPost()` method inside it.
All your other servlets should inherit from `ParentServlet`

So this should look something like this:

```
 public abstract class ParentServlet extends HttpServlet {
     ...
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){
        //your action logic here
     }
 }


 public class ChildServlet extends ParentServlet {
 }
```

Comment: when i call the child servlet its never gonna call the `doPost` of the parent. How will this work?

Comment: what makes you think so? if you do not define the doPost() method inside the ChildServlet, the doPost() from the parent will execute. if you havee a doPost() method in the child - just call super.doPost()